# After importing external data google spreadsheet changes are not reflected in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am importing json array from external website then I create table from the json array but changes dont get reflected in sheet , changes are only seen after refreshing the spreadsheet. 
I use setValues function.

```
var range = sheetnew.getRange(targetrow,targetcol, subarray.length , subarray[0].length);
range.setValues(subarray);
```

Comment: Perhaps this might help [SpreadsheetApp.flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: I used it but updates after 3 minutes I have lots of data imported.

Comment: Perhaps the setValues is not the slow step, it might be the importing which is the slow step.

Comment: Please copy the Execution transcript into your question so we can see where the time is being occupied.